# Is there a way to only HGETALL values in a hash larger than an int in Redis with Lua?

Tags: redis, lua

I'm trying to only get values in a hash larger than, say 1800, by Lua. I am new to Lua and I am not sure how to get the values from Redis, because the redis.call() method returns 1 only.

Here is my code. Here the keys of my hash is "1""2""3" etc, just to make it simpler.

```
for i=1,length do
  value = tonumber(redis.call("HGET", KEYS[1], i))
  if value >= 1800 then
    return redis.call("HGET", KEYS[1], i)
  end
end
```

Let's say I have a hash called Data like this:

HGETALL Data
 1) "monday"
 2) "1802"
 3) "tuesday"
 4) "1283"
 5) "wednesday"
 6) "3487"
 7) "thursday"
 8) "1899"
 9) "friday"
10) "1709"
11) "saturday"
12) "1909"
13) "sunday"
14) "1799"

I expect that when I use the HGETALL method, I get this:

1) "monday"
 2) "1802"
 5) "wednesday"
 6) "3487"
 7) "thursday"
 8) "1899"
11) "saturday"
12) "1909"

Comment: show your code. what do you mean with returns 1 only? the number 1?

Comment: @Piglet I edited the question. So in a hash like "1-1802, 2-1799, 3-1892, 4-1700, 5-1998", I expect "1802, 1892, 1998" but I only get "1802". The program terminates when it gets to "return".

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1,length do
  value = tonumber(redis.call("HGET", KEYS[1], i))
  if value >= 1800 then
    return redis.call("HGET", KEYS[1], i)
  end
end
```

This code tells your computer: look through all entries and give me the first one that is >= 1802.

If you want to get all values above you have several options.

You get a full list of entries using HGETALL and then filter the returned list of entries or you get single elements and put them into a list when they are >= 1800.

> The return statement is used to return values from a function or a
>   chunk (which is an anonymous function).

That means whatever function you're code is in will end if you return.

So using it inside your loop is not really an option if you want to process multiple entries.

Try something like

```
   -- create an empty table
    local greatValues = {}
    for i=1,length do
      value = tonumber(redis.call("HGET", KEYS[1], i))
      if value >= 1800 then
       -- insert any value that is >=1800 into the table
       table.insert(greatValues, value)
      end
    end
    -- return the list of results
    return greatValues
```